# Is there a way to entirely disable auto-complete suggestions from appearing on Google Chrome?

Tags: windows-7, google-chrome

As explained in the question, is it possible to disable the text field auto complete feature in chrome?
Screenshot: [image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/utjl2.png]